# Detect NOT touching for 3 seconds in iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, uikit, touch, uitouch

I am making a game with Sprite Kit.
I would like to give user some hints when he hasn't touched a screen for 3 seconds. What would be the best way to do this?

I was thinking about creating a `BOOL` value and change it in `touchesBegin`, then setting an `interval` which would trigger a method unless touching was detected.

Anyone has a better idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your idea is on the right track to start with.

But instead of using a "BOOL" value (which only tells you `TRUE` or `FALSE`), why not use two `NSTimeInterval` ivars (instance variables) to mark the last time a pair of `touchesBegan` and `touchesEnded` (or `touchesCancelled`) gets called.

If the value of `touchesBegan` is greater than `touchesEnded`, then an active touch is going on.

If the value of `touchesEnded` is more than 3 seconds beyond the current time (and the time of `touchesBegan` is still before `touchesEnded`), then it's time to show your hint.